# CSS conditional comments for other Browsers except IE?

Tags: html, cross-browser, conditional-comments

So far I know, the conditional comments are only supported for different Versions of IE.

Likeways, can we provide conditional comments for other browsers too.

If Yes, How? If no, what could be the best alternative?

Comment: I would suggest building for a browser that conforms to standards W3C.org etc. Then use the conditional comments to fix the page for ie?

Comment: Conditional comments are HTML, not CSS. There is no known conditional comment syntax for CSS (although there is conditional compilation for JScript). It's alarming that none of the answers seem to have pointed this out either.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn, Not Everyone know everything. I have retagged it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [CSS Browser Selector plugin](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/). I use it on my site, you basically just write the CSS and tell which browser you want it to target. I use it on my site and it works great!

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

[CSS Conditional Comments are meant only for IE.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx). However, you can detect Firefox:

If the following code fails to exclusively detect Firefox..

```
<!--[if !IE]>
  ...statements...
<![endif]-->
```

Use "Downlevel-revealed Conditional Comments" to get it working...

```
<![if !IE]>
  ...statements...
<![endif]>
```

Example to force Firefox to use an exclusive css..

```
<![if !IE]>

  <link href="css/ff.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<![endif]>
```

Having said that, you should not be much worried about other browsers which are **[standard-compliant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standards-compliant)**.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, CSS conditional statements are an IE exclusive. They should not be needed for other browser since they follow standards reasonably well. Why would you need them?

Comment: I know other browser follow quite same standards but not an exact match.

Comment: @Starx Browsers are different you can use javascript to try and catch these or you just have to understand there are differences between browsers it depends on how much time and effort you are willing to put in.

Comment: @Starx otherwise you can design your page without styling that causes differences between browsers I mean there are ways around it but not easy or efficient... The CSS browser selector plugin. Is probably one of the easiest ways to do it with script.

Answer (score 1):

There are not conditional comments for other browsers only IE and versions of IE.

You can using Javascript do checks for other browsers and apply styles as follows.

You can do a check for the browser to not be IE with conditional comments but just **no**.

I would suggest visiting [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/) and building your site to be functional with a standard conforming browser then use the conditional comments to fix up how it loads in IE if there are issues (there usually is).

Answer (score 0):

As noted in other answers there are no conditional comments for browsers other than IE. Using JS detection is the way to go here.

If you want to have the commented element affect the IE condition AND other browsers then simply do this:

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<link href="sample.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--><![endif]-->
```

As you can see from the syntax highlighting the link element is not commented out so it will be visible for non-IE browsers and for IE it will follow the condition (greater than IE 8 in this example).

Answer (score 0):

I wish there was a solution to this, especially for email rendering engines. There are even conditional comments for outlook, but none for Gmail.

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>

<![endif]-->
```