# Loading different CSS based on Android version

Tags: android, css

Is there a way to load different CSS files based on the Android version? Something like the conditional CSS that we use for IE versions:

```
<!--[if lte Android 2.3 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="android23-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3043402/870729